# Why does not Referer header use "same-origin" by default?

Tags: security, browser, http-headers, same-origin-policy, http-referer

Same origin policy is an important part of the security model so it is "on" by default for most things, but for the `referer` it does not seem to be so. The default for browsers seem to be `no-referrer-when-downgrade` which in practice is close to "always".

So I am wondering if there is any good reason for that?

Probably historical reasons or too important for ads I guess.